# C Static Function Confusion

Tags: c

I am trying to make the **s_cord_print** function visible in the **cord_s.c** file only. Currently the function is visible/runnable in **main.c** even when it is declared static.

How do I make the **s_cord_print** function private to **cord_s.c**?

Thanks!

**s_cord.c**

```
typedef struct s_cord{
  int x;
  int y;
  struct s_cord (*print)();
} s_cord;

void* VOID_THIS;
#define $(EL) VOID_THIS=&EL;EL

static s_cord s_cord_print(){
  struct s_cord *THIS;
  THIS = VOID_THIS;
  printf("(%d,%d)\n",THIS->x,THIS->y);
  return *THIS;
}

const s_cord s_cord_default = {1,2,s_cord_print};
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "s_cord.c"

int main(){
  s_cord mycord = s_cord_default;
  mycord.x = 2;
  mycord.y = 3;
  $(mycord).print().print();
  //static didn't seem to hide the function
  s_cord_print();
  return 0;
}
```

~

Comment: It looks like you're trying to do some rudimentary object-oriented programming in C with your `VOID_THIS` global and the `$(EL)` macro.  You're doing it wrong.  Also, although many compilers accept `$` as a valid identifier character, it is not valid according to the C standard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is:

```
#include "s_cord.c"
```

You should remove that.  Instead, create a `s_cord.h` file that contains only declarations, such as:

```
typedef struct s_cord{
  int x;
  int y;
  struct s_cord (*print)();
} s_cord;
```

and put:

```
#include "s_cord.h"
```

in `main.c` and `s_cord.c`.  You also need an `extern` declaration for `s_cord_default`.  So the complete code is:

s_cord.c:

```
#include "s_cord.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void* VOID_THIS;

static s_cord s_cord_print(){
  struct s_cord *THIS;
  THIS = VOID_THIS;
  printf("(%d,%d)\n",THIS->x,THIS->y);
  return *THIS;
}

const s_cord s_cord_default = {1,2,s_cord_print};
```

s_cord.h:

```
typedef struct s_cord{
  int x;
  int y;
  struct s_cord (*print)();
} s_cord;

#define $(EL) VOID_THIS=&EL;EL

extern const s_cord s_cord_default;
extern void *VOID_THIS;
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "s_cord.h"

int main(){
  s_cord mycord = s_cord_default;
  mycord.x = 2;
  mycord.y = 3;
  $(mycord).print().print();
  return 0;
}
```

You'll now get a error if you try to call `s_cord_print()` from main, as expected.

EDIT: I forgot to move the `$(EL)` definition, and it needed an extern for `VOID_THIS`.

EDIT 2: The correct compilation command is:

```
gcc s_cord.c main.c -o main
```

Comment: The header (and the implementation) would also need some sort of initialization routine for `s_coord` structure.

Comment: I tried making the edits but I'm getting the following error: undefined reference to `s_cord_print' It's coming from the $(mycord).print() line not the s_cord_print() line.

Comment: @Nikolai, do you mean `s_cord_default`?

Comment: Well I moved the s_cord_default into s_cord.h when I started getting that error along with the VOID_THIS void pointer.  I am really lost with what I am supposed to do.  How is the s_cord.c supposed to be included in the main.c by including the s_cord.h? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the edits!  I compiled with 'gcc main.c -o main' but that threw errors.  Then I compiled the function using 'gcc main.c s_cord.c -o main' but threw a warning about the printf in s_cord.c so I added stdio.h, but there is still no output to terminal.

Comment: What args would you use to compile the c program?

Comment: Yeah! Okay I had to move '#define $(EL) VOID_THIS=&EL;EL
void* VOID_THIS;' into s_cord.h,and '#include <stdio.h>' to s_cord.h and compiled using 'gcc main.c -o main'.  I think I need to read up on how header and .c files work because I really don't understand. I'm just curious but did you use a compiler?  Because I couldn't get what you posted to compile ever.  Maybe I did something wrong?

Comment: @Lime, if you're only compiling `main.c`, something is still wrong.  Headers and C files can be a bit tricky (and experience does help), but the main point is that you put declarations and prototypes, not initializations and definitions ("definitions" includes function bodies).

Comment: @Lime, I made a couple errors, but the latest version in the answer is fully tested with gcc.

Comment: I recommend not bothering with a global `VOID_THIS`.  Pass your object pointer as a parameter to each method.  When people do OO in C this is typically how it works.  The macro hackery just makes it look evil.  (Not to mention as written it is not thread safe, among other issues.)

Comment: @asveikau, very true.  I've just been making the code compile.  The design has issues.

Comment: It was more of a proof of concept idea that I was messing around with. :)  I like the shortnesses and dryness of OO C and especially know I don't have to worry about the namespace issues of short funcs or the incredibly long names like s_cord_print(&s); s_cord_midpoint(&s,&x).  's_cord_print(&mycord);s_cord_midpoint(&mycord,&x)' vs '$(mycord).print().midpoint(&x);'

Comment: @Lime, that's what I figured, and why I didn't mention the possible problems in my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

When you include s_cord.c from within main.c, the compiler sees your program as one big file.  It doesn't treat the included file as separate.  To make them separate, you have to compile them separately. Once you have compiled them separately, you will then have to *link* them to create the whole program.

When you try to compile each part, you will get errors, because each file doesn't know about the code in the other file.  Remember, this is what you were trying to accomplish with that one function.  Well, now you've got what you asked for, many times over.  Now, you have to create header files that explain the "missing parts".  Generally the files being compiled look at each other's ".h" files (they #include them) to get a bearing on the "missing" (actually, *external*) parts.  These are declarations, which tell the compiler "pretend you already know about this, and I promise that when we link everything, it will be provided".